# C++/CLI: Catching all (.NET/Win32/CRT) exceptions

Tags: .net, exception, c++-cli

I know this is frowned upon, but I'm out of options here. I'm developing a C++/CLI app that has a bug that I'm unable to track down - mainly because it's bypassing my current crash handler:

```
AppDomain::CurrentDomain->UnhandledException += gcnew UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(&LogAndExit);
Application::ThreadException += gcnew ThreadExceptionEventHandler(&LogAndExit);
Application::SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode::CatchException);
try 
{ 
    Application::Run(gcnew frmMain()); 
} 
catch (Exception^ ex) 
{ 
    LogAndExit(ex); 
} 
catch (...) 
{ 
    LogAndExit(); 
}
```

Standard .NET crash handling, I suppose. MSDN reports that some of the CRT exceptions will blow over the managed stack and silently abort the app.

I've been reading up on _set_invalid_parameter_handler, but even though I'm getting a LNK2001 error, it seems it can't be used with /clr:pure. Am I right, or am I just PEBKACing it up and missing a lib file?

Comment: Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown flags.

Comment: Can't. Don't have VS2010 installed on the target machines.

Comment: Would it not be possible to have the JIT dumper built in to windows grab a dump for you?

Comment: I'm actually writing a full memory dump whenever I can catch the exception - but that's not always the case. :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you run in `/clr` mode? If you can then try this:

```
#include <exception>
```

Then:

```
try
{
    try
    {
        Application::Run(gcnew frmMain()); 
    }
    catch(const exception& ex)
    {
        throw gcnew System::Exception(gcnew System::String(ex.what()));
    }
} 
catch (Exception^ ex) 
{ 
    LogAndExit(ex); 
} 
catch (...) 
{ 
    LogAndExit(); 
}
```

**Another thing to note:** if your application is multi-threaded, then you will only catch an exception from the thread in which `frmMain()` is running. So doing a catch-all on your entire application is impossible in that case!

Comment: I used to run in /clr, but one of my machines (ATM machines) didn't work. /clr:pure worked with all of them.

Comment: @hb, ok, well the other question is still valid: are you running multiple threads?

Comment: The C++/CLI process hosts a net.pipe WCF service, so I guess that's a yes. All of the methods are try/catch'd though (CLR)

Comment: @hb, and they're all logging the exceptions I assume? If they are, then you might might just have to track down the failure... of course, you already knew that...

Comment: Hah... yeah, precisely. Nothing gets shown, but sometimes it just dies.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this doesn't work for forms.

> In applications that use Windows Forms, unhandled exceptions in the
>   main application thread cause the
>   [**Application.ThreadException**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx) event to
>   be raised. If this event is handled,
>   the default behavior is that the
>   unhandled exception does not terminate
>   the application, although the
>   application is left in an unknown
>   state. In that case, the
>   UnhandledException event is not
>   raised. This behavior can be changed
>   by using the application configuration
>   file, or by using the
>   [**Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.setunhandledexceptionmode.aspx)
>   method to change the mode to
>   UnhandledExceptionMode.ThrowException
>   before the ThreadException event
>   handler is hooked up. This applies
>   only to the main application thread.
>   The UnhandledException event is raised
>   for unhandled exceptions thrown in
>   other threads.

Second,  there might be an unmanaged exception (which is not of type **[System::Exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.aspx)**).

```
try { Application::Run(gcnew frmMain()); } 
catch (Exception^ ex) { LogAndExit(ex); }
catch (...) { LogAndExit(new Exception("Some Unmanage exception"));
```

[**msdn**- How to catch exceptions in Visual C++](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815662)

Comment: Er, yeah. I forgot to copy that. Actual code in question now.

Comment: Did you read the MSDN article about how  forms are affected with CurrentDomain->UnhandledException ?

Comment: Yeah. Thing is none of those handlers are being used and just defaults to the default Windows "This app just crashed" dialog

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you try a __try / __except

```
__try 
{ 
  Application::Run(gcnew frmMain()); 
} 
__except(EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER) 
{ 
  LogAndExit(new Exception("Some Unmanage exception")); 
}
```

MSDN documentation here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s58ftw19(v=vs.80).aspx

If you wanted to get really tricky, you could try double wrapping it like this:

```
__try 
{ 
  try {
    Application::Run(gcnew frmMain()); 
  } 
  catch(SEHException^ e)
  {
    LogAndExit(new Exception("Some Unmanage exception")); 
  }
  catch(...) //Leave this out if you're /clr:pure
  {
    LogAndExit(new Exception("Some Unmanage exception")); 
  }
} 
__except(EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER) 
{ 
  LogAndExit(new Exception("Some Unmanage exception")); 
}
```

Structured exceptions are wrapped into SEHException^ generally.

You also need to take into account that you may in fact be catching the exception, but that something in your LogAndExit method is causing a secondary exception to be thrown which is actually what is ending your program.  Try stubbing out your LogAndExit function and see if you can make the crash happen silently rather than with a standard abort message and/or wrap your LogAndExit code in another try/catch that hides any exceptions.

As someone who has put significant time into C++/CLI, I can sympathize with your dilemma.  Hope this solution helps.

Additional MSDN documentation on C++/CLI exception handling:

How to: Define and Install a Global Exception Handler
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/171ezxzc.aspx

Exception Handling under /clr
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/633chdda.aspx

Comment: I'm using full dumps in the __except handler to try and figure out what the hell is going on. Anything else you can recommend? If I hadn't lost my hair already, I would've probably ripped it out by now.

Answer (score 0):

There are several types of exception handling. What you posted will only handle managed exceptions.

It's also possible for C++ code to throw unmanaged exceptions (particularly from the standard library). Furthermore, it's possible for unmanaged code to throw a Win32 exception.

[Start here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/633chdda.aspx) and read up on structured exception handling (Win32 exceptions). C++ exceptions and managed exceptions are built on SEH, so if you handle SEH at the top point of *every* thread in your process, you'll be covered.

Comment: Does that post also apply to /clr:pure?

Comment: I believe you're correct; clr:pure only supports managed code.

Comment: Managed exceptions use SEH, and managed handlers handle SEH exceptions.  If C++ code is using /EHa, any exceptions it throws will use SEH underneath as well.  There's no way for managed code to catch native C++ exceptions compiled with the synchronous model (/EHsc).

Comment: So, if I'm having a C++ exception, I'm SOL w/ depending on a stack trace to see where it's coming from?

Comment: I *believe* that it's not possible to get a C++ (or Win32) exception in clr:pure mode. *Almost* positive... At this point, your best bet is to get a minidump (e.g., via [ProcDump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx)) and load it into WinDbg or Visual Studio.

Comment: Hrm. Would going back to /clr or /clr:safe help? I'm having an issue with ONE machine only being able to run the app when it's in /clr:pure. All other machines can do it w/ the default. Also, just noticed I'm compiling using /EHa

Comment: I'd examine the crash dump. As I stated, I don't think it's possible to even cause a C++/Win32 exception in clr:pure mode.

Comment: Well, other than that... what else would show that dreaded Dr. Watson screen when using all those handlers? Other than an exception within the handler.

Comment: @hb: `/clr` (any flavor) always uses `/EHa`, SEH exceptions get mapped to .NET exceptions.  It's only when you link C++/CLI code with standard C++ code that some exceptions can slip through the cracks.  And Win32 SEH exceptions will be handled by .NET irrespective of C++ settings.

Comment: @Stephen: It definitely is possible to cause access violations, divide by zero, and other SEH exceptions, with `/clr:pure`.

Comment: @Ben: The point I was making is that divide by zero, etc., in clr:pure aren't exposed to your program as SEH exceptions; they'd *always* be .NET exceptions. Is that incorrect?

Comment: @Stephen: They're hardware traps, reported to the Windows kernel.  The kernel handles soft and hard page faults, stack expansion, etc., and exposes the rest of the traps to user mode as SEH exceptions.  .NET installs an SEH exception handler, and translates non-.NET exceptions into such things as `NullPointerException`, `Win32Exception`, etc.  That you see .NET exceptions does not mean that there aren't SEH exceptions.  `/clr:pure` does not cause these to start life as .NET exceptions, they still start in the hardware and get translated.

Answer (score 0):

Not every crash is an exception, at least not immediately.  It's entirely possible for a wild pointer to stomp on .NET internal data structures so badly that when an exception is thrown, the managed handler can't run correctly.

Try using a native handler instead.  Visual C++ provides `__try`/`__except`, but you'll need to make sure the handler is on the call stack of every thread in your program, and it's still possible for an exception to go unhandled (e.g. CreateThread with a pointer to an illegal instruction).  To deal with all edge cases, you should instead use [`SetUnhandledExceptionFilter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680634.aspx).

Note that with `/clr:pure`, all code is dependent on the CLR, and so subject to failure due to runtime corruption.  Even native handlers might depend on corrupted state, although they're less fragile that MSIL-based handlers.  For robust error-handling, you really need code running outside the process.