# Crash filling data adapter

Tags: c++, ado.net, command-line-interface

I am perplexed figuring out why a malformed query of a gmail account in outlook crashes my application instead of simply raising an exception. Seems that there is an uncaught win32 exception based on calling the code from unmanaged C++. The error goes away when I change the outlook profile location. I still don't understand why my .NET code could not catch the exception as I had nested > 20 exceptions to try to catch the issue.

I also can't directly debug the code in .NET since I am unable to set the STAAttribute and my compiler Visual Studio 2010 Professional doesn't allow me to debug C++/CLI code.
http://winterdom.com/2007/02/jetmapiandsta

The query error is simple with # missing on a date
`SELECT * FROM inbox WHERE Body Like '%BWIC%' And rECEIVED>=#07/26/2012`

I've tried adding many exceptions to the catch statement, but can't prevent the crash.

```
System::Data::DataSet ^db_DataSet=gcnew System::Data::DataSet;  
int const Fill_Result=db_Adapter.Fill(db_DataSet);
}
catch (System::Exception ^ex) {
    ex;
}
catch (...) {
   ;
}
finally {
   if (db_Conn)
       db_Conn.close();
}
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue today, did you get any solution to it.

Comment: Can you create a SSCCE that someone can run on their own computer?

Comment: Which Win32 exception? This seems to be an external exception. Are you using COM?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628412/c-cli-catching-all-net-win32-crt-exceptions) thread. It may be helpful.

According to it you can catch the exception in native environment and throw an exception into the managed world.

```
#include <exception>


 try
{
    try
    {
        Application::Run(gcnew frmMain()); 
    }
    catch(const exception& ex)
    {
        throw gcnew System::Exception(gcnew System::String(ex.what()));
    }
} 
catch (Exception^ ex) 
{ 
    LogAndExit(ex); 
} 
catch (...) 
{ 
    LogAndExit(); 
}
```