# failed to create c# object from CLI code

Tags: c++-cli

I am trying to access a managed function from native code. 
I created a c++/cli dll in visual studio 2010 with CLR option.
This is my c# code:

```
namespace ManagedNamespace
{
    public class Managed
    {
        public void CSharpFunc()
        {
             .
             .
             .
        }
    }
}
```

This is my c++\CLI code (the project refer to the c# project - and I compile this code to Wrapper.dll):

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{ 
#endif
    __declspec(dllexport) void CLIFunc(const std::string& a, const std::string& b, std::string& c)
    {
        System::String^ new_a = gcnew System::String(a.c_str()); //OK
        System::String^ new_b = gcnew System::String(b.c_str()); //OK
        Text::StringBuilder^ new_c = gcnew Text::StringBuilder(""); //OK
        ManagedNamespace::Managed^ m = gcnew ManagedNamespace::Managed(); //this line is the problematic line
        m->CSharpFunc();
    }
```

I call this function from another dll and get EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER when I create ManagedNamespace::Managed object. This is the code:

```
typedef void (WINAPI *CLIFuncPtr)(const std::string& a, const std::string& b, std::string& c);
.
.
.
HMODULE mod = LoadLibraryA("c:\\mydir\\Wrapper.dll");
if (mod!= NULL)
{
    CLIFuncPtr FuncPtr = (CLIFuncPtr)GetProcAddress(mod, "CLIFunc");
    if (FuncPtr != NULL)
    {
         FuncPtr (aa, bb, cc);
    }
}
```

Appreciate any help,
Thanks

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Is this relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628412/c-cli-catching-all-net-win32-crt-exceptions Can you make the debugger break on all exceptions and see what's gone wrong?

Comment: exception: EEFileLoadException * _ptr64 at memory location 0x....

Comment: The CLR has no hope of finding your C# assembly if you don't copy it in the same directory as the EXE.  The backup plan is to register it in the GAC so it can always be found.

Answer (score 0):

I think that LoadLibrary works only with unmanaged code